"webpack: command not found" error when running "npm start"
Each time I enter in "npm start", it says webpack: command not found (as shown in the screenshot below)
output returned after "npm start"
In my package.json file, my dependencies include the following (as further shown in the screenshot below):
"dependencies": 
 "webpack": "^4.47.0",
 "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
 "webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.2"
 }
}

json file
Does anyone know what the issue is?
I've tried removing the webpacks - all of them, including webpack, webpack-cli, webpack-dev-server. I've also tried playing around with the versions to get them compatible with one another. But I'm not sure what to do anymore.
